# Taking values from a dataframe to loop for operations into another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

```
vocab
 wordIDx V1
    1  archive
    2  name
    3  atheism
    4  resources
    5  alt

wordIDx newsgroup_ID    docIdx  word/doc    totalwords/doc totalwords/newsgroup wordID/newsgroup    P(W_j)
1   1   196 3   1240    47821   2   0.028130269
1   1   47  2   1220    47821   2   0.028130269
2   12  4437    1   702 47490   8   0.8
3   12  4434    1   673 47490   8   0.035051912
5   12  4398    1   53  47490   8   0.4
3   12  4564    11  1539    47490   8   0.035051912
```

For each wordIDx in vocab, I need to compute the following formulae:
For instance wordIDx = 1 ;
my value should be

```
max(log(0.02813027)+sum(log(2/47821),log(2/47821)))
= -23.73506
```

I have the following code for now:

```
 classifier_3$ans<- max(log(classifier_3$`P(W_j)`)+ (sum(log(classifier_3$`wordID/newsgroup`/classifier_3$`totalwords/newsgroup`))))
```

How can I loop in a way that it considers all wordIDx from vocab dataframe and computes the above example as I have highlighted.

Comment: Could you provide your sample data via the dput(head(dataframe, 10))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but you really need to clean your column names.

```
vocab <- read.table(text = "wordIDx V1
1  archive
2  name
3  atheism
4  resources
5  alt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

classifier_3 <- read.table(text = "wordIDx newsgroup_ID    docIdx  word/doc            totalwords/doc totalwords/newsgroup wordID/newsgroup    P(W_j)
1   1   196 3   1240    47821   2   0.028130269
1   1   47  2   1220    47821   2   0.028130269
2   12  4437    1   702 47490   8   0.8
3   12  4434    1   673 47490   8   0.035051912
5   12  4398    1   53  47490   8   0.4
3   12  4564    11  1539    47490   8   0.035051912", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

classifier_3 <- classifier_3[!duplicated(classifier_3$wordIDx), ]
classifier_3 <- merge(vocab, classifier_3, by = c("wordIDx"))
classifier_3$ans<- pmax(log(classifier_3$`P.W_j.`)+ 
                     (log(classifier_3$`wordID.newsgroup`/classifier_3$`totalwords.newsgroup`) +
                            # isn't that times 2?
                            log(classifier_3$`wordID.newsgroup`/classifier_3$`totalwords.newsgroup`)),
                        log(classifier_3$`wordID.newsgroup`/classifier_3$`totalwords.newsgroup`))
```

Comment: classifier_3 <- classifier_3[!duplicated(classifier_3$wordIDx), ] is removing the second row with wordIDx=1.I would like to keep all the rows intact;and compute the formulae).Is it possible ?

Comment: You can use `classifier_3 <- merge(classifier_3, vocab, by = "wordIDx", all.x = TRUE)` to merge.

Comment: It works.But,I need to loop in through all the wordIDs and find the ans which is max(log(P(w_j)) + sum(all rows where wordID exists for all docIDx)..
I am not sure how to edit the third line for that.Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: `pmax` is the parallel version of `max`, it works on columns. Calculate the 2 cols you want the max as an intermediate result and then apply pmax.